# shape of Vector in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am confused by the fact that

```
a = np.array([1,2])
a.T == a  # True
```

and also

```
I = np.array([[1,0],[0,1]])
np.dot(a, I) = np.dot(I, a) # both sides work
```

Is the shape of vector (or array) in this case 1*2 or 2*1 ?

Comment: Have you tried doing np.shape(a)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vector `a` has shape `2`, not `1 × 2` nor `2 × 1` (it is neither a column nor row vector), which is why transposition doesn't have any effect, as [transposition by default reverses the ordering of the axes](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html).

Numpy is [very lenient about what kinds of arrays can be multiplied using `dot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html):

> it is a sum product over the last axis of `a` and the second-to-last of `b`